# Select by property

Tags: css, properties, css-selectors

I'm replacing an html table with css 'display' properties (table, table-row, etc).  (If I need to change the title, will do).

Is there a way to select in CSS by the display property?

Can't find any info on this.

How to make this valid?:

```
.myClass[display=table-cell]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible, you can select by attributes, and their values, but not by CSS properties. Nor do I think it would make sense to do so, since the selector could easily be invalidated by the style-rules applied to the selected element(s), if such existed, leading to incredibly complex CSS parsing rules and, potentially, infinite loops.

It is possible to achieve something similar, with JavaScript, but definitely not with just CSS.

References:

- [CSS Selectors (Level 3)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).
- [CSS Selectors (Level 4), Editor's draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#syntax).

Comment: oh right!  duh.  many thanks for added knowledge about infinite loops!

Comment: Avoid linking to unstable specs unless they're essential to the answer :)

Comment: Yes, being able to select by CSS properties will cause all kinds of cascading problems. Very simple example: `[display=none] { display: block; } [display=block] { display: none; }`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot select elements by a CSS property itself. You can select by HTML attributes (which as you surely know is the syntax you are using there) or by class, but not (without using JavaScript) by CSS property alone.

Answer (score 2):

You only can select this way if it's explicit on your html.

```
<div class="mydiv" display="table-cell"></div>

.mydiv {
    width: 100px;
}

div[display='table-cell'] {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ALN4/1/)

Comment: love the innovation!  would totally give check if it were technically correct. :/

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy Why not just use something like: `<div class="mydiv" data-layout="table-cell">` and change Ricardos example to suit. It should pass validation.

Comment: Well, I was hoping for laziness since I already have it worked out for html table.  If I'm going through the agony of having to actually do something ;))  I mightaswell just do it right with classes etc.  Thanks a lot for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't any way to select in CSS by property.